# run iron ajax in synchronous way in Polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am trying to convert below code of AngularJS 1.6 into polymer 2.0

**AngularJS**

```
for ( int i=0; i<=10; i++ )
{
 // call rest service for Rates
    var rates = fxRateService.query({ids : rateIds}, function() {
        //do some processing here
    }
}
```

**Polymer Code**

```
for ( int i=0; i<=10; i++ )
{
 // call rest service for Rates
 this.$.rateAjax.url = 'api/v1/fxrates?ids=' + rateIds;
 this.$.rateAjax.generateRequest();

}

requestEnd() {
    // do processing based on the response retrieved

}
```

The problem is that in Polymer when FOR loop runs, the program does not run in synchronous way. If FOR loop runs 5 times, the program makes 5 calles to rest service but the Program comes to requestEnd method after all iterations of FOR loop are complete.

What I want is, it should call Rest Service, wait for the service to return and execute requestEnd method, then make second call to Rest Service as done by AngularJS code.

Can you please guide me?

Comment: so you wish to do 10 request with different queries...
wouldn't it be faster to do them all at the same time and process each response as it returns?
or do you need to wait for all responses to be able to do your processing?

Answer (score 0):

If you design your "requestEnd" method as a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) then you can do something like this:

```
function queryAll(i){
    if(i === 10)
    {
        return;
        // All done
    }

    return this.$.rateAjax.generateRequest().then(requestEnd).then(()=>{
        i++;
        return queryAll(i);
    })   
}
```